# Ubuntu 12.04 redirection command does not work

Tags: file, redirect, ffmpeg, ubuntu-12.04

I need to stuck logs from ffmpeg.

So I command like below.

```
ffmpeg -f rtsp -rtsp_transport tcp -ss 600 -i rtsp://aaa.bbb -vframes 1 out.jpg>aaa_log.list
```

I already confirm that this command makes fine outputs, except ">aaa_log.list" part.

It makes file with the name "aaa_log.list", but does not write anything.

My OS is Ubuntu 12.04 64bit and ffmpeg version is 1.2.0.

Thnaks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try 2> instead of >.  ffmpeg is probably writing to STDERR instead of STDOUT

Comment: Indeed! Thanks:D I replaced '>aaa_log.list' to '2 > aaa_log.list', and it works. Wonderful!

Comment: No problem -- I had to deal with the same issue a few weeks ago :)